# Eliminar o duplicar filas en función del número de veces que aparece repetida SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Escribe las sentencias DDL y DML necesarias para borrar filas duplicadas de la tabla t196 y
dejar el siguiente número de filas:

- Si una fila aparece dos o más veces, dejamos dos copias de la fila
- Si una fila aparece una única vez, creamos una copia de la misma para que aparezca
  exactamente dos veces

A los efectos de contar las filas, los nulos se consideran como si fueran no nulos.
Sabemos que en la tabla t196 existe una dependencia funcional de la columna x a la columna b. Eso
significa que para cada valor de x el valor en la columna b es único.

---

La tabla es:

```
drop table t196;
create table t196(x INTEGER, b VARCHAR2(5));
insert into t196 values(1,'r');
insert into t196 values(1,'r');
insert into t196 values(1,'r');
insert into t196 values(1,'r');
insert into t196 values(1,'r');
insert into t196 values(2,'p');
insert into t196 values(2,'p');
insert into t196 values(3,'w');
insert into t196 values(null,'a');
insert into t196 values(null,'a');
insert into t196 values(null,'a');
commit;
```

---

Sabemos que seleccionar elementos según el número de veces que aparecen con:

```
SELECT x,b
FROM t196 
GROUP BY x,b
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

Podemos cambiar a `HAVING COUNT(*)>=2` etc.

Podría hacer un `CASE` con ambos casos pero en el `THEN` ¿Cómo puedo eliminar o duplicar las filas?